# How to resolve cannot find module error in react app creation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Error: Cannot find module './lib/pack.js'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\tar\tar.js
- C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\tar-pack\index.js
- C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js
- C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js

Comment: I'd guess you're missing that file for some reason; try renaming `C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx` to `C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx-oops` or something and retry.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.